# How to include whitespace in Select dropdown

Tags: javascript

How would I include a blank space before the `agencyName` in the example below?

```
}
else if (item.level === 2) {
    $("#sel_Agency").append(
        $("<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>")
        .text(item.agencyName)
        .val(item.id)
    );
```

Comment: You can use padding-left on the options to achieve that there would be some empty space... see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNf75/)

Answer (score 0):

this way:

```
               } else if (item.level === 2)
                    {
                        $("#sel_Agency").append(
                        $("<option></option>")
                        .text('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + item.agencyName)
                        .val(item.id)
                    );
```

Comment: That actually concats to my string and display in the select box.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what is done to the display text as you would be keying what is selected on the items ID. This would provide the result you want.

Comment: This woultn't work as it woul output '&nbsp;' as string in the option. If you would just put a normal backkspace it would be cutted out... See [fiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNf75/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking to just have groups in your select boxes, but there is a specification for groups in selects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Ex from MDN:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
        <option>Option 1.1</option>
    </optgroup> 
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
        <option>Option 2.1</option>
        <option>Option 2.2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 3" disabled>
        <option>Option 3.1</option>
        <option>Option 3.2</option>
        <option>Option 3.3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```